# Inherit context (this) in the declaration of an object literal? Is `self` okay?

Tags: javascript

Is it posisble to remove the `self` variable in this snippet:

```
class Foobar {
  constructor() {
    let self = this; // How do I remove self?
    let fizz = buzz.doSomething({
      aFunction: self.someFun 
    });
  }

  someFun() {
  }
}
```

One option could be to define an empty object and then assign the function with the key.

```
let options = {};
options[aFunction] = this.doSomething;
let fizz = buzz.doSomething(options);
```

If the options object becomes a list of 10 things wouldn't be better to have them all wrapped by a single pair of braces?

Am I overthinking it?

Comment: Why not use a `bind` call to bind the context of `this` to the constructor instead? You won't need `self` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely use `this` in your code snippet. `this` only changes it's meaning when you're invoking a function using the `function(){}` syntax.
In your case you're just creating an object literal, where `this` is still the same as `self`.

```
constructor() {
    let fizz = buzz.doSomething({
       aFunction: this.someFun 
    });
}
```

This works perfectly fine. Even made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9o1ymrna/3/).

If you want to go into more depth check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on the MDN.

Comment: When you call *any* function with *any* function call syntax, the value of `this` inside the function body depends on how it is called. Anonymous functions are no different from any other function.

Comment: @MichaelGeary: Doesn't apply to bound functions and arrow functions.

Comment: @FelixKling Exactly, that's why I wrote a function using the `function(){}` syntax :)